# Do I have to initialize the component state in both constructor() and componentWillReceiveProps()?

Tags: reactjs, redux, lifecycle

In my **React/Redux** application, I trigger an API call in the index.js (The entry point) as I want the data to be available even before user navigates to the component.

Actually, this approach helps to reduce the user's wait time as we'll have the data loaded before user reaches the component.

In our use-case, we need to initialize the component state with the props (`props` are passed from store). I faced below issue in the approach.

- **case 1: Let's assume user has reached the component before the API
  returned that data.** In this case, that particular store object will be
  empty and the props (which is passed from `react-redux` `connect`
  wrapper) will be undefined/null. So I need to render `"Loading.."`
  message. When the data arrives, we initialize the component state
  using `setState()` in `componentWillRecieveProps().`
- **case 2: If data has arrived before user navigates to the component.**
  For this case, We can either use `constructor()` or `componentWillMount()` to initialize the state from `props`, as `props` is having the data. I can't rely only on `componentWillRecieveProps()` as, it'll not execute during the initialization life cycle.

So I ended up doing the same initialization steps in 2 places as component should handle both cases. Is this a right approach? or Is there any better approach to avoid these kind of DRY code.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Why do you want to initialize component state in the `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle hook? Drop you whole logic responsible for fetching the data inside `componentDidMount` and just use a simple condition inside ur render function (if data fetched, render it, if not - render `Loading`).

Comment: Initialize the component in the constructor only. If data is not ready, render "loading..." instead of rendering the component. When the component is ready, mount it, and the initialization with occur in the constructor. The other option is to refactor initialization to a method, and call it both in the constructor, and in componentWillReceiveProps.

Comment: Yes, that would help provided I initialize the API call  during Component initialization. But, In my case I want the data to be pre-fetched even before the component initialization. So that users will not have "wait time", when they reached component through navigation in my "SPA" application.

Comment: @OriDrori Thanks. In this way I can avoid DRY. But the common method will have setState() which cannot be used in constructor(). However, I'll use the common method from componentWillMount() and componentWillReceiveProps() as setState() can be used in componentWillMount().

Comment: @BalamuruganN - componentWillMount will work fine, and won't cause rerender when you setState.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same exact issue that you outlined and also wanted a DRY solution, so I ended up creating a HOC (higher order component) for this purpose:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-prepare-wrapper

It lets you assign a single function to be called for both `componentWillMount` and `componentWillReceiveProps`.